# Postfix to reject all unauthenticated users

Tags: postfix

My Postfix configuration is the following:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions =  permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_helo_hostname
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unlisted_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_multi_recipient_bounce, permit
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks
smtpd_etrn_restrictions = reject

smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
```

Currently, if I telnet to my mail server from anywhere I am able send an email without authentication with any `HELO` and any `MAIL FROM:` to any of the email addresses configured on my mail server. I want to reject that and allow sending to my mail server's addresses only after successful authentication.

**UPD** Is it possible at all? I've just realized that this might actually be the way a mail receiving system works in general (the sender does not need to auth on my server to send a mail to me). Or am I mixing something up?

Comment: http://www.mailradar.com/openrelay/ use this to check whether your server is open for relay or not.

Comment: If you require authentication in order for a sender to send mail to you, you won't be getting any mail at all other than from your own users. Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you describe as happening is correct, if you want to receive mail from people outside your domain on the rest of the Internet. Only *outgoing* mail from your own users, destined for other places on the network, needs to be authenticated.